# "No space left on device" error on Debian Buster, /dev/sda1 100% Full

Tags: debian, debian-buster

I've been setting up a Debian 10 VM over the last couple of days and, as I was installing CMake (after running `sudo make install`), I got the following error message:

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:125 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/home/pedro/cmake-3.15.2/Modules/FindOpenThreads.cmake" to
  "/usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindOpenThreads.cmake".


make: *** [Makefile:84: install] Error 1
```

So I decided to check what would happen if I were to manually copy the file, at which point I got `"No space left on device"`. It struck me as strange, as the actual disk size I allocated to the VM was only about 30% full. After running `df` I got the following output:

```
udev                3023668       0    3023668   0% /dev
tmpfs                608712    8488     600224   2% /run
/dev/sda1           6080640 6064256          0 100% /
tmpfs               3043560    4872    3038688   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5120       4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs               3043560       0    3043560   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7            463826    2333     433026   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5           2303044  516380    1649960  24% /var
/dev/sda8          20847812 1470388   18295364   8% /home
tmpfs                608712      12     608700   1% /run/user/1000
```

And for `df -i`:

```
udev            755917    382  755535    1% /dev
tmpfs           760890    586  760304    1% /run
/dev/sda1       390912 206799  184113   53% /
tmpfs           760890      8  760882    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           760890      3  760887    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           760890     17  760873    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7       121920     42  121878    1% /tmp
/dev/sda5       150480  14136  136344   10% /var
/dev/sda8      1332688  37799 1294889    3% /home
tmpfs           760890     24  760866    1% /run/user/1000
```

I don't actually know if /sda1 has anything to do with the errors, but I thought it might be worth mentioning. It should be noted that I am still able to download files and apt-get packages with no problem whatsoever, so not too sure what to make of it.

Comment: Well, you ran out of space on the root partition (sda1, ~6 GB, mounted on /). What's your question?

Comment: Well if that's the problem... I guess I'll just have to find a way to extend it. Is that it?

Comment: You can try to move the partitions around, sure (maybe with parted/gparted?). Or redo the VM and put everything into one big one.

Comment: I guess I'll give GParted a try, I remember it not being too difficult. If I mess it up then I'll just re-do it. Thank you!